# Python ElementTree find() using a wildcard?

Tags: python, find, wildcard, elementtree

I am parsing an XML feed in python to extract certain tags. My XML contains namespaces and this results in each tag containing a namespace followed by tag name.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:rte="http://www.rte.ie/schemas/vod">
    <id>10038711/</id>
    <updated>2013-01-24T22:52:43+00:00</updated>
    <title type="text">Reeling in the Years</title>
    <logo>http://www.rte.ie/iptv/images/logo.gif</logo>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://feeds.rasset.ie/rteavgen/player/playlist?type=iptv&amp;showId=10038711" />
    <category term="feed"/>
    <author>
        <name>RTE</name>
        <uri>http://www.rte.ie</uri>
    </author>
    <entry>
        <id>10038711</id>
        <published>2012-07-04T12:00:00+01:00</published>
        <updated>2013-01-06T12:31:25+00:00</updated>
        <title type="text">Reeling in the Years</title>
        <content type="text">National and international events with popular music from the year 1989.First Broadcast: 08/11/1999</content>
        <category term="WEB Exclusive" rte:type="channel"/>
        <category term="Classics 1980" rte:type="genre"/>
        <category term="rte player" rte:type="source"/>
        <category term="" rte:type="transmision_details"/>
        <category term="False" rte:type="copyprotectionoptout"/>
        <category term="long" rte:type="form"/>
        <category term="3275" rte:type="progid"/>
        <link rel="site" type="text/html" href="http://www.rte.ie/tv50/"/>
        <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://feeds.rasset.ie/rteavgen/player/playlist/?itemId=10038711&amp;type=iptv&amp;format=xml" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.rte.ie/player/#v=10038711"/>
        <rte:valid start="2012-07-23T15:56:04+01:00" end="2017-08-01T15:56:04+01:00"/>
        <rte:duration ms="842205" formatted="0:10"/>
        <rte:statistics views="19"/>
        <rte:bri id="na"/>
        <rte:channel id="13"/>
        <rte:item id="10038711"/>
        <media:title type="plain">Reeling in the Years</media:title>
        <media:description type="plain">National and international events with popular music from the year 1989. First Broadcast: 08/11/1999</media:description>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://img.rasset.ie/00062efc200.jpg" height="288" width="512" time="00:00:00+00:00"/>
        <media:teaserimgref1x1 url="" time="00:00:00+00:00"/>
        <media:rating scheme="http://www.rte.ie/schemes/vod">NA</media:rating>
        <media:copyright>RTÉ</media:copyright>
        <media:group rte:format="single">
            <media:content url="http://vod.hds.rasset.ie/manifest/2012/0728/20120728_reelingint_cl10038711_10039316_260_.f4m" type="video/mp4" medium="video" expression="full" duration="842205" rte:format="content"/>
        </media:group>
        <rte:ads>
            <media:content url="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=512x288&amp;iu=%2F3014%2FP_RTE_TV50_Pre&amp;ciu_szs=300x250&amp;impl=s&amp;gdfp_req=1&amp;env=vp&amp;output=xml_vast2&amp;unviewed_position_start=1&amp;url=[referrer_url]&amp;correlator=[timestamp]" type="text/xml" medium="video" expression="full" rte:format="advertising" rte:cue="0" />
            <media:content url="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=512x288&amp;iu=%2F3014%2FP_RTE_TV50_Pre2&amp;ciu_szs=300x250&amp;impl=s&amp;gdfp_req=1&amp;env=vp&amp;output=xml_vast2&amp;unviewed_position_start=1&amp;url=[referrer_url]&amp;correlator=[timestamp]" type="text/xml" medium="video" expression="full" rte:format="advertising" rte:cue="0" />
            <media:content url="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=512x288&amp;iu=%2F3014%2FP_RTE_TV50_Pre3&amp;ciu_szs=300x250&amp;impl=s&amp;gdfp_req=1&amp;env=vp&amp;output=xml_vast2&amp;unviewed_position_start=1&amp;url=[referrer_url]&amp;correlator=[timestamp]" type="text/xml" medium="video" expression="full" rte:format="advertising" rte:cue="0" />
        </rte:ads>
    </entry>
<!-- playlist.xml -->
</feed>
```

When the XML is parsed each element is soming out as:

```
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}updated
.....
.....
{http://www.rte.ie/schemas/vod}valid
{http://www.rte.ie/schemas/vod}duration
....
....
{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}description
{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail
....
```

As I have 3 different namespaces and I cannot gurantee that they will be always the same then I woul prefer not to hard specify each tag like so:

```
for elem in tree.iter({http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
    stream = str(elem.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id').text)
    date_tmp = str(elem.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published').text)
    name_tmp = str(elem.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title').text)
    short_tmp = str(elem.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content').text)
    channel_tmp = elem.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}category', "channel")
    channel = str(channel_tmp.get('term'))
    icon_tmp = elem.find('{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail')
    icon_url = str(icon_tmp.get('url'))
```

Is there any way that I can put a wildcard or something similar into the find so it will simply ignore the namespace?

```
stream = str(elem.find('*id').text)
```

I can hardcode them as above but it would be my luck that down the line the namespace would change and my queries stop returning data..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why would the namespaces change? The namespace is part of the element name--if the namespace changed then it's fundamentally a different element and your program would probably need to change too. Namespaces are not something that change on a whim.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an XPath expression with the local-name() function:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="ns">
  <tag/>
</root>
```

Assuming "doc" is the ElementTree for the above XML:

```
import lxml.etree
doc = lxml.etree.parse(<some_file_like_object>)
root = doc.getroot()
root.xpath('//*[local-name()="tag"]')
[<Element {ns}tag at 0x7fcde6f7c960>]
```

replacing `<some_file_like_object>` as appropriate (alternatively, you can use `lxml.etree.fromstring` with an XML string to get the `root` element directly).

Comment: Sorry, first post had "root.find", needs to be "root.xpath" :)

Comment: Thanks for this. How can I use this above?

Comment: For example, if you want to get the text for all 'id' nodes below a given node (stored in 'elem' in the following example), you could use [str(node.text) for node in elem.xpath("//*[local-name()='id']")]

Comment: Do I need a different import than: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET ?

Comment: Don't think so. I used lxml.etree in above example.

Comment: lxml.etree.ElementTree has xpath() function while xml.etree.ElementTree and xml.etree.cElementTree don't.

Comment: what is the full example including your import statement? What is root? What is doc?

Comment: @StealthRabbi: updated answer with `import` statement and assignment to `doc`... `root` was already defined in the original answer.